# Silently install InstallShield EXE file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, installation, installshield, silent

I have exe file created with InstallShield 2018 Express Edition. I need to create PowerShell script that will silently install that exe on different computers.

I have tried all the options I found on google and nothing works. 
I tried to generate setup.iss answer file with command `setup.exe /r` and `setup.exe /r /f1'-path'` and that didn't worked. I could not get that file.

Commands I tried:

```
setup.exe /s /v /qn
setup.exe /s /v "/qn"
setup.exe /s /v /qb 
setup.exe /q /norestart
setup.exe /qb /norestart
setup.exe /passive
```

I converted exe into msi and tried with `msiexec` but that did not work too.

The problem with all this commands is that UI keeps popping up and I need to click all the buttons to complete the install.

I found also that silent install could be disabled for particular exe.
The exe file I use is created with InstallShield project in Visual Studio 2017, so I went to create new build with Silent Install Switch included but I wasn't able to find that option.

The way I partly succeeded is with

```
setup.exe /a
```

then UI is prompted, I click all the buttons and some setup.msi file with size of 1.6mb is generated (setup.exe is 270mb). The app doesn't get installed.

Running that *setup.msi* of 1.6mb with `msiexec` command successfully installs app silently on computer where that msi is generated.
The problem is that setup.msi can not be used on other computers.

Answer (score 2):

You tried setup.exe /s /v "/qn" but you were so close. There should be no space after the /v option. Try setup.exe /s /v"/qn"

As Ansgar pointed out you need to differentiate between the InstallShield options (setup.exe) and the MSI options. To run the InstallShield setup.exe (bootstrapper) silently just use /s. The /v"/qn property=value" is the pass through option to pass into the MSI within the bootstrapper. The list of [MSI command line options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/command-line-options), those that can go in between the quotes after /v.

Answer (score 0):

`/qn` and `/qb` are [MSI options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/command-line-options), not [InstallShield options](http://www.silentinstall.org/InstallShield). For InstallShield installers the "silent" option is `/s`:

> **/s    Silent mode.** For an InstallScript project, the command Setup.exe /s runs the installation in silent mode, by default based on the responses contained in a response file called Setup.iss in the same directory.

Try this:

```
setup.exe /s
```

If that doesn't suffice you need to look at what parameters the installer actually accepts (`setup.exe /?`).

Answer (score 0):

I have used that help command already, but now when I run it just to post screenshot of available commands I noticed space between /S  and /v/qn and that is what caused all the trouble.

I did not have that space in my previous attempts.

So the working command is:

```
setup.exe /S /v/qn
```

Thanks